# How does the matchExpressions filter for PodDisruptionBudget work for non Deployment or Daemonset pods?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a single PDB that captures a bunch of system pods I use to prevent scaling issues related to them being marked unmovable if they do not have one:

```
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
...
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
    - key: k8s-app
      operator: In
      values:
      - kube-dns
      - gke-metrics-agent
      - fluentbit-gke
```

Now those are all Daemonsets or Deployments with multiple replicas.

But what happens if I do this?

```
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
...
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchExpressions:
    - key: k8s-app
      operator: In
      values:
                - kube-proxy
                - event-exporter
```

`event-exporter` and `kube-proxy` are pods created on each node. So there is exactly one pod on each node and my PDB is filtering on `k8s-app`.

What happens when a node drains?

Will these pods be marked unmovable or is the aggregate of all pods matching `k8s-app:kube-proxy` in namespace `kube-system` taken into account?